# How do I change the x-axis label orientation/slant using chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-visualization, chartkick

I am using chartkick to draw a line chart.  This works fine except that labels on the x-axis are overlapping and unreadable.  I want to change the orientation of these labels on the x-axis so that they are angled out at 45 degrees from the axis.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

```
<%= line_chart User.all.group_by_day(:created_at, last: 14, discrete: true).count %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I didn't realise I was using google-visualisation and when I did it was relatively straight forward to find the answer:

```
<%= line_chart User.all.group_by_day(:created_at, last: 14, discrete: true).count, {library: { hAxis: {slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 45 } } } %>
```

For further options see here: [Google Charts - Visualisation: Line Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?hl=fr)